# Javascript onclick show/hide for multiple rows (Dynamic content)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm having a list of users where the admin can approve/decline.For these two action i'm using show/hide oncllick the code works.But in multiple rows for any action button onclick it shows/hide the content.I want paticular row's  action button 'ld show/hide the content,on click of that button.How can I solve this?
 Here is My view code laravel blade,

```
<script>
    function showhide() {  
        var div = document.getElementById("collapse1");  
        if (div.style.display !== "none")   
            div.style.display = "none";  
        else  
            div.style.display = "block";  
    }  
    </script>
```

**Content:**

```
<div>
    <button href="#collapse1" class="btn btn-success nav-toggle"  onclick="showhide()">Action</button>
</div>
@if($user->approved == 0)
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
    <span>
        <a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}"><img alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/n/a/E/b/t/check-mark-button-hi.png" 
        style="height: 48px; width: 48px"  /></a>
    </span><br/>
@else
    <span>
        <a href="{!! route('decline', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}">
            <img alt="" src="https://images.onlinelabels.com/images/clip-art/TzeenieWheenie/TzeenieWheenie_red_green_OK_not_OK_Icons_1.png" 
    style="height: 48px; width: 48px"/>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
@endif
```

**Script**

```
@pushonce('custom-scripts')
 <script 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 @endpushonce
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: For example having two action  buttons ,when i'm clicking 2nd action button 1st action button's content works

Comment: This line: `var div = document.getElementById("collapse1");`, doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: But when I try void's answer it totally doesnn't work " var div = document.getElementById(elem.href.replace("#", ""));"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It conflict `id`
You need change `id`:

```
id="collapse1" => id="collapse{$user->id}"
```

js and html function like https://jsfiddle.net/ft9xprnb/3/ .You can see result by click link and content function edited: `elem.getAttribute("href")`

```
function showhide(elem) 
    {  
        console.log(elem.getAttribute("href"));
        var div = document.getElementById(elem.getAttribute("href").replace("#", ""));

        if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
            div.style.display = "none";  
        }  
        else {  
            div.style.display = "block";  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But this not works when I change this "collapse{$user->id}" show/hide not works

Comment: Try   id="collapse1" => id="collapse{$user->id}"  and href="#collapse1" => href="collapse{$user->id}"  and use function showhide(elem)  @void

Comment: It works still I change the id and href ,after I change the code it doesn'tworks I can't guess what'll be the issue

Comment: You can debug html render by browser, inspect in dev tool to see what id and href render

Comment: Shows the error in console  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at showhide (driver:458)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (driver:399)

Comment: If Laravel Blade Templates you can try {{ $user->id }}

Comment: As i say earlier it doesn't work,what esle 'll be the issue?

Comment: Any problem with jquery versions

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549 You inspect and see what id and href of div and button . Previous post {{ not { as  first post

Comment: function showhide(elem) 
    {  console.log(elem);//add this line and view in console

Comment: " <button href="collapse1{{ $user->id }} " class="btn btn-success"  onclick="showhide(this)">Action</button>"

Comment: <div  id="collapse1{{ $user->id }} "  style="display:none">

Comment: And in script                                                                                     
                     function showhide(elem) 
        {  
            var div = document.getElementById("collapse1");  
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
                div.style.display = "none";  
            }  
            else {  
                div.style.display = "block";  
            }  
        }

Comment: function showhide(elem) { var div = document.getElementById("collapse1");=>document.getElementById(elem);

Comment: if id,href = collapse14 and document.getElementBy‌​Id(elem) it will work filne

Comment: "document.getElementBy‌​Id(elem);"  updated this code Now          
                          function showhide(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
            document.getElementBy‌​Id(elem);
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
                div.style.display = "none";  
            }  
            else {  
                div.style.display = "block";  
            }  
        }

Comment: oh sorry i have mistake, try void post  function showhide(elem) 
    {console.log(elem);   
        var div = document.getElementById(elem.href.replace("#", ""));  
        if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
            div.style.display = "none";  
        }  
        else {  
            div.style.display = "block";  
        }  
    }

Comment: driver:460 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at showhide (driver:460)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (driver:400)
showhide @ driver:460
onclick @ driver:400
driver:459 <button href=​"#collapse14 " class=​"btn btn-success" onclick=​"showhide(this)​">​Action​</button>​

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` in html

```
<button href="#collapse1" class="btn btn-success nav-toggle"  onclick="showhide(this)">Action</button>
```

And then in JS

```
function showhide(elem) 
    {  
        var div = document.getElementById(elem.href.replace("#", ""));  
        if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
            div.style.display = "none";  
        }  
        else {  
            div.style.display = "block";  
        }  
    }
```

This way the elem you will be passing to click will be the clicked element.

Comment: When I replace this line "var div = document.getElementById(elem.href.replace("#", ""));  " the code totally doesn't work What 'll be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing content to this

```
<div>
    <button href="#collapse1" class="btn btn-success nav-toggle" onclick="showhide()">Action</button>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
    @if($user->approved == 0)
        <span>
             <a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}">
                 <img alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/n/a/E/b/t/check-mark-button-hi.png" style="height: 48px; width: 48px"/>
             </a>
         </span>
        <br/>
    @else
        <span>
            <a href="{!! route('decline', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}">
                <img alt="" src="https://images.onlinelabels.com/images/clip-art/TzeenieWheenie/TzeenieWheenie_red_green_OK_not_OK_Icons_1.png" style="height: 48px; width: 48px"/>
            </a>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: It does the same

Comment: did you try it?